# Trying to get value from other table using any in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

My query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
RIGHT JOIN table2 on table1.ID = any(table2.parents)
WHERE table1.ID = 1
```

My first table is:

```
ID   | desc         
123  | Data123
231  | Data231
```

My second table is:

```
ID   | parents
1    | {123,231}
2    | {123}
```

But this query isn't working. I am trying to get the data from both 123 and 231, how do I fix this?

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean? Do you get an error? If yes, which one?

Comment: I am getting empty rows back, but it should return 2 rows.

Answer (score 1):

> `any(table1.parents)`

parents doesn't exists in  table1.

Try to change places

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
RIGHT JOIN table2 on table1.ID = any(table2.parents)
WHERE table2.ID = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what exactly you want, but if you just want to find rows in table1 where the IDs are present in table2.parents, the following should do it:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select *
              from table2 t2
              where t1.id = any(t2.parents))
order by t1.id;
```

If you want information from table2 as well you need a join  (and I don't think you want an outer join):

```
select *
from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t1.id = any(t2.parents)
order by t1.id
```

Due to the nature of a join that would return the row `(123,Data123)` **twice** - don't know if you want that or not.

Example:  http://rextester.com/PUOL76353

Comment: These both still return zero rows for me. What i am trying to get is like both rows of table1 and joined by the first row twice of table2.

Comment: @Antiwoutertje With the sample data you have given both **do** return rows, see my example (link). If this doesn't work for you, you need to show us the sample data that "doesn't work" for you.

Comment: I think i made a small mistake by myself, i am puzzling by myself now but i think i almost solved it. Thank you.